# Local Martingales in a Finite Time Horizon setting

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I apologise if this question has been answered somewhere else. Consider the following definition.

Let $T \in [0, \infty), d \in \mathbb{N}$, let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P, (\mathbb{F}_t)_{t \in [0, T]})$ be a stochastic basis, let $M\colon [0,T] \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be an $(\mathbb{F}_t)_{t \in [0, T]}$-adapted stochastic process and let $(\tau_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\colon \Omega \rightarrow [0,T]  \cup \{\infty\}$ be a non-decreasing sequence of $(\mathbb{F}_t)_{t \in [0, T]}$-stopping times such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(\tau_n=T)=1$ and such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that the stopped process $M^{\tau_n}$ associated to $M$ and $\tau_n$ is an $(\mathbb{F}_t)_{t \in [0, T]}$-P-martingale. Then $M$ is called a local $(\mathbb{F}_t)_{t \in [0, T]}$-$P$-martingale.

My question is: Is this definition of local martingales correct? Specifically, I want to know if the stopping times $(\tau_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ have been correctly defined or if instead we should have the condition that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(\tau_n=\infty)=1$.

If this definition is indeed correct, then what would be the definition of a  locally bounded stochastic process $X\colon [0, T] \times \mathbb{\Omega} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? Specifically, to show local boundedness do we take a sequence of stopping times that converge $P$-a.s. to $\infty$ or stopping times that converge $P$-a.s. to $T$?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
After going through O. Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability (Chapted 6, page 97), I have discovered that the range for a stopping time is defined to be the closure of the time domain. In this case it will simply be the set $[0, T]$. This then begs the question of how we can prove that a stochastic process is locally bounded. The usual technique involves considering a sequence of so-called first exit-times i.e. times at which the stochastic process first exceeds the value $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work in this case because these stopping times will converge $P$-a.s. to $\infty$. So this sequence of stopping times won't work...